# Checking if a $_COOKIE value is empty or not

Tags: php, variables, cookies, superglobals

I assign a cookie to a variable:

```
$user_cookie = $_COOKIE["user"];
```

How can I check if the `$user_cookie` received some value or not?

Should I use `if (empty($user_cookie))` or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) like so:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
$user_cookie = $_COOKIE["user"];
}
```

This tells you whether a key named `user` is present in `$_COOKIE`. The value itself could be `""`, `0`, `NULL` etc. Depending on the context, some of these values (e.g. `0`) could be valid.

PS: For the second part, I'd use `===` operator to check for `false`, `NULL`, `0`, `""`, or may be `(string) $user_cookie !== ""`.

Comment: Just thought of this: aren't cookie values *always* strings if they exist, aka if it `isset()`?

Comment: Testing just now, it seems that using `setcookie()` to assign an empty string, false, or NULL causes it to **not** be set, but setting it to an integer `0` causes it to be set with a string value of `"0"`. I never knew that.

Comment: @Wesley: PHP setcookie() probably casts truthy values to a string and other values to "".

Comment: An empty string actually caused the cookie to not even be set, as in `isset()` returns `false`

Answer (score 5):

These are the things empty will return true for:

- "" (empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as float)
- "0" (0 as string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a declared variable not in a class)

Taken straight from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

So to answer your question, yes, `empty()` will be a perfectly acceptable function, and in this instance I'd prefer it over `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

Try empty function in php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

You can also use isset http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: `empty()` will return true on string value of zero, a legitimate value for a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), however keep in mind, like `empty()` it cannot be used on expressions, only variables.

```
isset($_COOKIE['user']); // ok

isset($user_cookie = $_COOKIE['user']); // not ok

$user_cookie = $_COOKIE['user'];
isset($user_cookie); // ok
```

(*`isset()` **is** the way to go, when dealing with cookies*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE["user"])) {
   // code if not empty
}
```

but sometimes you want to set if the value is set in the first place

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
   // code if the value is not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cookie variable is an **array**:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || empty(unserialize($_COOKIE['user']))) {
    // cookie variable is not set or empty
}
```

If your cookie variable is **not** an **array**:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || empty($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    // cookie variable is not set or empty
}
```

I use this approach.