# how should I use php to set cookie for this situation

Tags: php, forms, cookies, save

if I have the function below that after you entered (must) your first and last name then a radio button is chosen but I want to set a cookie lets say a minute or something if that person comes back again then automatically lets' say there'll be a welcome back message instead of saying input your name and select a radio button....how can I do that?

I have this as my 1.php for asking name

```
echo "<form action='lab17a.php' method='get'>";
echo "First Name: ";
echo "<input type='text' name='fname' /><br/>";
echo "Last Name: ";
echo "<input type='text' name='lname' /><br/>";
echo "Red<input type='radio' name='bgcolor' value='red'><br/>";
echo "Blue<input type='radio' name='bgcolor' value='blue'><br/>";
echo "Yellow<input type='radio' name='bgcolor' value='yellow'><br/>";
echo "Green<input type='radio' name='bgcolor' value='green'><br/>";
echo "<input type='submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

and this is 2.php after submitting and will test if the fields are entered...

```
if(empty($_GET["fname"]) || (empty($_GET["lname"])))
{
    echo "Press the browser's BACK button and enter both names.<br/>You must enter a first name last name";
}
elseif(!(empty($_GET["fname"])) && (!(empty($_GET["lname"]))) && (empty($_GET["bgcolor"])))
{
    echo "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Leaving the background color of the Web page default color (white)";
}
elseif(!(empty($_GET["fname"])) && (!(empty($_GET["lname"]))) && (!empty($_GET["bgcolor"])))
{
echo "<body bgcolor='" . $_GET["bgcolor"] . "'>" . "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Background color changed to the selected color";
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the setcookie method. It has an attribute in which you can set the expire time.

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

So say your formcheck is complete in 2.php and you have no errors (I'm using a string here with formErrors, if it's empty, I set my cookie).

```
if ($formErrors == "") {
    setcookie("name", $nameValue, time() + 60); // Say you want the cookie to contain the filled in name and you want it to expire in 60 secs.
}
```

Then in your 1.php you check if the cookie is set and if so, you do what you want (in your case, show a message).

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    // show your message
}
```

Inside your if statement you can use `$_COOKIE['name']` to get the value.
Hope this helps

Comment: ya I checked out php.net read it but still not sure where I should setcookie and $_COOKIE...:(

Comment: Well, if I understand what you're doing your form check is on 2.php right? Then you should do the setcookie method if the form check is complete. You can call the $_COOKIE value anywhere. I'll edit my post to give you a code sample

Comment: thanks a lot...still new here trying to figure out how things works.  not even sure if I'm doing it right doing the form check on 2.php because I'm told that after submit then the cookie will be set and if I re enter the page 1.php which will then not display the form asking for name and stuffs

Comment: so I'm not using setcookie in 2.php if the conditions are met and then call $_COOKIE in 1..php?

Comment: totally!!! I was then starting to think something simliar and starting to get it working too :P but just wonna see how your sample is to get me understand it more :P thanks a lot ~!

Comment: by the way....I'm just wondering IF I use empty instead of isset would it work properly too? Just a curious question....because I read through the threads and examples in php.net what I feel is that they are only kind of opposite like isset=true and empty=false but some thread says there is difference but couldn't really understand their long long explanation

Comment: The way I think it is is that isset returns true or false based on whether the key exists (in this case name). Empty returns true or false based on whether the value assigned to the key is "" or null or... This thread handles this question partially, especially in the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435786/checking-if-a-cookie-value-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have submit button on this page. set cookie using javascript on click of submit button and next time when user comes on this page check if that cookie is set using php if yes flash a message that welcome back.